# How can I rig a multiple-axis robot?

Tags: rigging

Is it possible to create a animation of multiple axis motion or robot?

The key point of my question is kinematics. For example, when the end of a SCARA robot performs a straight line in 3D world, each joints rotates at different but specific speed at specific position. Is it possible to be carried out by Blender?

Is there any Blender function that supports the above movement? Or if Blender accepts third party coordinates, such as text file of pre-calculated axis angles from Matlab?

Comment: You are looking for Inverse kinematics (google that) and Blender can do it.

Comment: better make that an answer. :-)

Comment: @Jerryno Do you mind answering?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

> Is there any Blender function that supports the above movement?

You are looking for solving the motion with [Inverse Kinematics](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Inverse_kinematics), in fact exactly like an industrial robot solves joint trajectories needed for the robot to guide some tool along some trajectory.

[Here](https://docs.blender.org/manual/animation/armatures/posing/bone_constraints/inverse_kinematics/introduction.html) is the documentation.

You put IK constraint(s) on last bone of bone chain(s) you want to control to comply with some given position/motion given by another object or bone (the *target* for the solver).

For every bone of this chain you can also limit the degrees of motion for each joint. The settings are under *Bone* tab in *Properties* panel.

Comment: Thank you very much for your comment! This is exactly what I am looking for and is helpful for people like me who are not familiar with Blender. I will start to survey this data immediately.